# How to combine vlookup and hyperlink function?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vlookup

I am trying to have the values that my vlookup function returns act as a hyperlink that will go to the value it pulled from another sheet in the same workbook.

There are thousands of lines that I need to hyperlink and I can't go one by one, right clicking and manually changing them.

If anyone has advice to solve this problem, please let me know. Below is my vlookp formula.

=VLOOKUP(A:A,'Cost Estimates'!A:C,3,FALSE)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? From what I can see you just need to replace "A:A" with "A1" and drag this formula down.

Comment: Of course! I need the value this vlookup returns to act as a hyperlink. So, trying to combine these two formulas into one. Usually, I get an error that states it cannot be found.

Comment: What do you mean "act as a hyperlink"? Like, you click on it and it takes you to that line in the code?

Comment: Something along the lines of =HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(A:A,'Cost Estimates'!A:C,3,FALSE). If that is possible. I can't seem to get it right. The closest formula that I get to the functionality I need is                     =HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",'Cost Estimates'!C2),'Matter Tracking Sheet'!K2)

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible without VBA, as Excel does not properly allow you to 'link' to another cell determined through indirect formula. I tried HYPERLINK(INDIRECT(MATCH(A1,'Cost Estimates'!A,0))) and it just takes you to A1, instead of the linking cell on the Cost Estimates tab.

Comment: To be clear, though, do you actually need it to jump you there, or is it enough for it to just give you the address of where it is?

Comment: Ah, was hoping to avoid VBA. Yes, I need it to jump to the cell or at least the row the data sits in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'Cost Estimates'!A:C,3,FALSE)
```

to return the column C value corresponding to A1.

Then use:

```
=MATCH(VLOOKUP_RETURN,C:C,0)
```

to get the index of that in column C.

Then use:

```
="#'Cost Estimates'!C"&INDEX_VALUE
```

to build a hyperlink address.

Finally, you can use HYPERLINK to construct the hyperlink. Putting it all together in a single formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Cost Estimates!C"&MATCH(VLOOKUP(A1,'Cost Estimates'!A:C,3,FALSE),'Cost Estimates'!C:C,0),VLOOKUP(A1,'Cost Estimates'!A:C,3,FALSE))
```

Hope that does the trick.

Comment: Does this actually create a workable hyperlink for you? In Excel 2010 clicking on this doesn't work as it isn't able to really detect the end location of the hyperlink properly.

Comment: I fiddled around with this solution and you're right, it doesn't create a workable hyperlink. Although, it is clickable. Wasn't returned the value I needed from the 2nd sheet so I changed it to A2 instead of keeping it at A1.                                                                                                                =HYPERLINK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(VLOOKUP(A2,'Cost Estimates'!A:C,3,FALSE),'Cost Estimates'!C:C,0),3,1,1,"Cost Estimates")),VLOOKUP(A2,'Cost Estimates'!A:C,3,FALSE))

Comment: I just updated the formula --- try it now. I get an active link that also jumps between sheets.

Answer (score 0):

To list address of the matching cell, you can do this:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,'Cost Estimates'!A:A),3,1,1,"Cost Estimates")
```

But this won't create a hyperlink, just a visible address.